# Figures or plots with accompanying thumbnails, like in RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I create plots within a single chunk of an R-Studio markdown file, they appear in a nice array with clickable thumbnails:

[image: Figures in RStudio]

However, when I publish as an HTML file, these figures are simply displayed vertically, one after the other. Is there any way to achieve the way that it originally looks in RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to output what RStudio shows you, but you can do this and a lot of other HTML formatting yourself using the [knitrBootstrap](https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap) package.

Check out the end of [this example](https://rawgit.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap/master/vignettes/maps.html) for a clickable-thumbnail example.